# How do I access the Lync 2010 whiteboard feature in the UCMA 3.0 SDK?

Tags: ucma, lync-2010

I am building a web application that uses the UCMA API 3.0 to establish a Lync 2010 chat between our customers on our website and our support team.  Chat and even video work great but, one of the reasons we picked Lync is the great Whiteboard feature in the communications tools.  I cannot seem to find any reference to it in the UCMA sdk though...  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I know this question is _pretty old_, but still is it possible to achive **Lync 2013 whiteboard feature in the UCMA 4.0 SDK?** i tried the answer you posted, but is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright - I found the answer finally and wanted to post it here in case other people needed it.  When you create a conference in UCMA you have to add "MCU" types to it that allow the different features Lync supports.  Here is a quick example of how to "schedule" the conference:

```
ConferenceScheduleInformation inf = new ConferenceScheduleInformation();
inf.AccessLevel = ConferenceAccessLevel.Everyone;
inf.IsPasscodeOptional = true;
inf.Description = "Description";
inf.ExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);

inf.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.Meeting));
inf.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.InstantMessaging));
inf.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.ApplicationSharing));

app_Endpoint.ConferenceServices.BeginScheduleConference(inf, EndScheduleConference, app_Endpoint.ConferenceServices);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that Whiteboarding is directly supported in UCMA 3.0 - [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg448283.aspx) in the SDK suggests that you would need to implement a custom solution:

> UCMA 3.0 allows an application to reach out with outbound notifications, take actions on behalf of a user, or as a client, to a far-end that is a UC-capable endpoint, and create and manage multiple modalities (audio, IM) as well as providing the ability for an application to extend the default modalities for custom media (such as whiteboarding)

Could you change your solution to have the remote user use the [Lync Web App](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/welcome-to-microsoft-lync-web-app-HA101908015.aspx), which does support whiteboarding? It should be possible to use UCMA to establish the parties in the conversation. Either user could then start a whiteboard session.

Comment: I am actually trying to do that.  I start a conversation, escalate to a conference, and link the user to the external conference URL.  But the web application (as well as the windows client) will only allow IM, audio, and video.  Whiteboard screen sharing, etc... are all disabled.

Comment: Strange - I've had sharing working before. I seem to remember that it needed an extra plugin, which you get prompted to install when first trying to share. Also, the meeting organiser needs to ensure the other users are made presenters in order to share - see here - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/share-your-desktop-and-programs-in-lync-web-app-HA101913621.aspx

Comment: I'm also very interested in customizing whiteboarding Lync feature. Asked here: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754265/customizing-whiteboard-and-powerpoint-sharing-lyncs-features-or-reusing-in-custo and here - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ucclientsdk/thread/286887a4-1f73-4f10-90ba-0ec4a74aeab1