# Customizing whiteboard and powerpoint sharing Lync's features or reusing in custom app

Tags: .net, lync-2010, lync

Lync 2010 allows sharing of PowerPoint presentations and doing whiteboarding on them. But its UI isn't suitable for us. We're going to use Lync on kiosk-like PC (without physical keyboard and mouse, only touchscreen). We need to customize Lync's UI in presentation sharing mode.
How to do this?
Is it possible to custome Lync client's UI?
Is it possible to reuse some these Lync's features in a custom application? I understand that Lync provides Lync SDK for using Lync's features in custom applications (LyncClient class). But I can't find anything about whiteboarding and presentation (and application) sharing in the SDK API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lync SDK allows you to programmatically start desktop sharing conversations, but doesn't give you any control over the experience. The desktop sharing / presentation UI components are also not available in Lync UI suppression mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what should I do? 
Are you aware of any possibilities in Lync Web App customization? It seems to have all needed controls internally (in its Silverlight app, not in SDK)...

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately this appears to be one of those cases where you don't really have any good options.